# Another XSLT-thing

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having this annoying problem. I'm trying to extract the values of attributes, but somehow additional characters comes along.

> ```
> <Objs>   
> <Obj RefId="0">
> <TN RefId="0">
>   <T>System.Data.DataRow</T>
>   <T>System.Object</T>
> </TN>
> <ToString>System.Data.DataRow</ToString>
> <Props>
>   <I32 N="Counter">1</I32>
>   <S N="DoctorInCharge">Williams Pete</S>
>   <I32 N="Sorting">2</I32>
> </Props>   
> </Obj>   
> <Obj RefId="1">
> <TNRef RefId="0" />
> <ToString>System.Data.DataRow</ToString>
> <Props>
>   <I32 N="Counter">2</I32>
>   <S N="DoctorInCharge">Smith Patricia</S>
>   <I32 N="Sorting">3</I32>
> </Props>   
> </Obj>   
> <Obj RefId="2">
> <TNRef RefId="0" />
> <ToString>System.Data.DataRow</ToString>
> <Props>
>   <I32 N="Counter">3</I32>
>   <S N="DoctorInCharge">Lee Sung</S>
>   <I32 N="Sorting">4</I32>
> </Props>   
> </Obj>   
> <Obj RefId="3">
> <TNRef RefId="0" />
> <ToString>System.Data.DataRow</ToString>
> <Props>
>   <I32 N="Counter">4</I32>
>   <S N="DoctorInCharge">Pittman James</S>
>   <I32 N="Sorting">5</I32>
> </Props>   
> </Obj>
> ```

And when I try this stylesheet:

```
><xsl:template match="Objs">
> <html> 
> <body>               
>   <img width="400" height="100" src="icon.png" class="CalloutRightPhoto"/>
>   <h1>CytostaticaReg - DoctorInCharge</h1>   
>     <table border="1">
>       <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
>         <th>Element name</th>
>         <th>Contence</th>
>       </tr>
>       <tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
>         <th>Doctor in charge</th>
>       </tr>
>       <xsl:for-each select="Obj">
>         <tr bgcolor="#ff0000">
>           <td><xsl:value-of select='@RefId'/>" /></td>
>         </tr> 
>       </xsl:for-each>   
>     </table>       
>   </body>      
> </html>
></xsl:template>
```

All chosen values of "RefID" will be displayed in the browser as:

> 0" />
>   1" />
>   2" />
>   3" />

....but I would really like to remove '" />' so that it will be displayed as:

```
0 
1 
2 
3
```

How could this be done?

Many thanks for your contributions:-)

/Paul

Comment: `<td><xsl:value-of select='@RefId'/>" /></td>`, what's wrong with this line? Do you not see the problem...?

Comment: Please give your question a title which describes what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your original:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select='@RefId'/>" /></td>
```

with the right one:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select='@RefId'/></td>
```